# How to speed up Django when doing new changes to the views.py and urls.py?

Tags: django, python-3.x, iis

Currently we have our production Django web app hosted in IIS and we have noticed that when we add new changes into the `views.py` or, specially, the `url.py` files, the changes take a while to be reflected in the server, that is, it can take an hour to see the changes. This does not happen when I modify the html files, changes take effect immediately.

We also broke on purpose the `url.py` file by adding incorrect lines such as `url1234567(r'^tickets/$', views.tickets_calculate),` but this line did not take effect until several minutes later.

**Questions**

1. Why do the changes in these files take so long?
2. How can I speed up this process of "refreshing of `views.py` and `urls.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some trial and error tests we found out the following:

For question 1, it seems that this is not an isolated problem because in other web server applications such as **Apache**, **IIS** or **nginx**, the time it takes for pages to be reflected depends on the default parameters that are established by these web server applications. How to modify these parameters? This is an off-topic question and more research should be devoted to solve it.

For question 2, we did not find where to modify these parameters of "refreshing" time in IIS so the alternative solution was to run our Django web app in localhost inside of our server with `python manage.py runserver` and we started noticing the effects immediately for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but consider: `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 graceful` to restart the webserver just after pulling the changes.